# Syntax error which won't let me create a table in my database

Tags: mysql

So I have the following code:

```
String SQLString = $"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (" +
                                $"`SQLID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                                $"`socialClub` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT \"\"," +
                                $"`userName` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT \"\"," +
                                $"`Cash` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0`," +
                                $"`Level` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `1`," +
                                $"`Age` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0`," +
                                $"`Health` INT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT `1`," +
                                $"PRIMARY KEY (`SQLID`));";
```

And I get the following error when I turn on my server:

```
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`0`,`Level` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `1`,`Age` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0`,`Hea' at line 1
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Don't use backticks around your DEFAULT clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly escaping the `DEFAULT` clause. Just remove the backticks and your query is syntactically correct.